# Joining multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I know this topic has been discussed already but not as specific as I need it in my case

Let´s say I have 4 dataframes with the same columns but different time ranges (rows). I set the date as index and would like to join the dataframes into a single new one. To do that I put the dataframes into a list and tried to join them in a loop, but I can´t get it work.

If I execute I get the following error:

*ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['attr1', 'attr2'], dtype='object'*

By default "join" should be joining on index, so I wonder why this error comes up?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here´s some code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['2019-04-29', 5, 9],
    ['2019-04-28', 4, 61],
    ['2019-04-27', 24, 9]]),
    columns=['Date', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df1 = df1.set_index(['Date'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['2019-04-25', 5, 19],
    ['2019-04-24', 14, 16],
    ['2019-04-23', 4, 9]]),
    columns=['Date', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['Date'])

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['2019-04-29', 15, 49],
    ['2019-04-25', 4, 36],
    ['2019-04-23', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['Date', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df3 = df3.set_index(['Date'])

df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['2019-04-29', 15, 49],
    ['2019-04-10', 4, 36],
    ['2019-04-5', 14, 9]]),
    columns=['Date', 'attr1', 'attr2'])
df4 = df4.set_index(['Date'])

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

for df in (dfs):
    df.join(df, how='outer')
```

The wanted format looks like this:

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
['2019-04-29', 15, 49, 5, 19, 15, 49, 15, 49],
['2019-04-10', 4, 36, 14, 16, 4, 36, 4, 36],
['2019-04-5', 14, 9, 4, 36, 4, 36, 4, 36]]),
columns=['Date', 'attr1_x', 'attr2_x', 'attr1_y', 'attr2_y', 'attr1_z', 'attr2_z', 'attr1_v', 'attr2_v'])
df5 = df5.set_index(['Date'])
```

Comment: How many columns do you think your output DataFrame should have? Can you hand craft your expected output for the data in your question?

Comment: You're almost there. Just replace your for loop and join statement with
pd.concat(dfs).

Comment: @VasuDevan Try `pd.concat(dfs).loc['2019-04-29',:]`, I doubt this is the OPs intention. The question is what the OP wants to do about the duplicate dates. Aggregate them, repeat them or make separate columns? I suspect it is to aggregate them. But if it's repeat them, then `pd.concat` is correct.

Comment: I don´t want to aggregate but to repeat them, so I can perform further operations. It seems concat is the best solutions. The thing is the number of dataframes varies and therefore needs to be dynamic, hence the for loop. Is there a way to concat dynamically?

The wanted columns format would look like this:
Date (index) attr1_w attr2_w attr1_x attr2_x attr1_y attr2_y attr1_z attr2_z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right, how='outer', left_on='Date', right_on='Date'), dfs)
>>> df_final
        attr1_x attr2_x attr1_y attr2_y attr1_x attr2_x attr1_y attr2_y
Date                                                                      
2019-04-29       5       9     NaN     NaN      15      49      15      49
2019-04-28       4      61     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-04-27      24       9     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-04-25     NaN     NaN       5      19       4      36     NaN     NaN
2019-04-24     NaN     NaN      14      16     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-04-23     NaN     NaN       4       9      14       9     NaN     NaN
2019-04-10     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN       4      36
2019-04-5      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN      14       9
```